# Search a column header and then filter all sheets using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to filter all sheets based on a certain column header named "LOC code". This header doesn't not appear on the same column number across the sheets.
How do I locate the desired column and then filter by an array of criteria?
Thanks!

I've used the following code to filter, but it's only based on the position of the field ("10") and no the column header.

```
Sub AllSheetsAutofilter()

    Dim p As Integer, q As Integer
    p = Worksheets.Count
    For q = 1 To p
        With Worksheets(q)
            .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=10, _
                Criteria1:=Array("ABM", "AC8"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End With
    Next q
End Sub
```

Comment: There are many ways to find the location of a string in a range.  The `Range.Find` method is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar for work. All that I did was record a macro of me filtering LOC in each tab.

If you need to use this just once, then you won't find this useful.

If you're going to use it multiple times and on each tab, the LOC is always in the same position (it can be different on other tabs), you may find it useful.  Regarding the LOC location, what I mean is, for tab 1, if LOC is always in column 2, and for tab 2, LOC is always in column 4, you can use this.

**EDIT**

Here are a few other hacks that you may want to try. Will it be okay for you to cut the LOC column and place it in column A? If so, this will be a good start. I've tested it for one sheet. You just need to add some type of code that runs it for each sheet in the workbook. If this is a suitable solution for you, I can find that code for you.

```
Sub Macro7()
Cells.Find(What:="LOC", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Cut
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
End Sub
```

I started another possible solution that you can try completing. Record a macro of you doing the following: Search for LOC. Filter LOC. Use the Relative Reference when recording your macro.

Comment: Thanks tmsdajpa, I'll try it but the thing is, that LOC isn't always on the same column. Let me explain the situation:
I receive the file from one person. What this person does, is attaching all the different sheets he receives in one file. So sheet 1 won't have the same order always.
That's the reason for searching for the column header instead of the column position.
Thank again.

Comment: I just edited my post with a partial solution. See if that'll work.